# Add element alternatively to a list

Tags: python

I want to place an element alternatively between any two elements of a list.

```
l1 = list('abcde')
fill = 'z'
```

How it should look like:

```
['a', 'z', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'z', 'd', 'z', 'e']
```

My solution:

```
fill = 'z'
l2 = [fill]*(len(l1)-1)
[x for t in map(None, l1, l2) for x in t if x]
```

Is there a better approach, i.e. that doesn't need to create another list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if x` will cause your code to break if any element of `l1` is falsy (e.g. `None`, `0`, or an empty string).

`map(None, …)` is a bit unusual.  Usually, that would be handled by some kind of "zip" — either the `zip()` builtin function, or one of the zip functions in `itertools`.

If you are going to use list comprehensions, then you might as well go all the way and not use `map()` at all.

```
[element for item in l1 for element in (item, fill)][:-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

What if `fill` were a comma?  Does that remind you of a common string-handling idiom?

```
>>> ','.join('abcde')
'a,b,c,d,e'
```

The only remaining task is to convert that result into a list.

Therefore, the solution would be better written as:

```
list(fill.join(l1))
```

Comment: This only holds as long as `fill` is just one character.

Comment: Why didn't you give a better example? Better yet, why don't you ask a less hypothetical question that represents your concrete application?

Comment: @MERose join works for multichar strings too

Comment: @Caridorc But the `fill` would get split into multiple elements in the result.

Comment: @200_success: I'm not saying your solution is not working nor that it doesn't answer my question. I am just noting restrictions to your answer for further reference.

Answer (score 4):

`map(None, ...)` is deprecated and removed in Python 3, so it should be avoided (favour `zip`). Plus, you should really be `zip`ing over a generator, like

```
from itertools import repeat

def interleave(sep, elems):
    ret = (elem for pair in zip(repeat(sep), elems) for elem in pair)
    next(ret, None)
    return ret
```

Use `itertools.izip` on Python 2.

Personally, I would much prefer this written out in long as

```
def interleave(sep, elems):
    def generate():
        for elem in elems:
            yield sep
            yield elem

    ret = generate()
    next(ret, None)
    return ret
```